# Updating Ember Nested Model and Template

Tags: jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js, jstree

I have a template which is backed by a model. It is a tree list view which has the first level folders.

I have an action handler which is used to update the sub-child any of the first level folder. From the action I need to update the model so that the sub-child is updated in the template.

I can add another first level folder by directly updating the model using pushObject.

How can I add/update the sub-child nodes of any parent level folders.

In template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h2> Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <ul>
      {{#each item in model}}
         <li>{{item.foldername}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
    <button {{action 'createFolder'}}>Add First Level Folder</button>
    <button {{action 'createSubFolder'}}>Add Sub Folder</button>
</script>
```

In my app.js:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here ;
});

App.folder = Ember.Object.extend();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
      return [{'foldername': 'Folder 1'}, {'foldername': 'Folder 2'}, {'foldername': 'Folder 3'} ];
   },
   actions: {
       createFolder: function () {
          var obj = App.folder.create({'foldername': 'Folder 4'});
          this.modelFor('index').pushObject(obj);
       },
       createSubFolder: function () {
          var subObj = App.folder.create({'foldername': 'Sub Folder 1'});
          //How to update this in the model below of any first level folder.
       }
  }

});
```

JSBIN Demo [Link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qebas/9/)

Comment: Is this what you're trying? http://jsbin.com/mozix/1/edit

Comment: @blessenm Thanks for updating this. We need to update multiple children. I want to add a child folder and again add another grand child folder. Can I have many sub level of sub-folders added recursively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to render recursively using partials.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
    {{#each model}}
      {{partial "tree"}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_tree">
  <li>{{foldername}}</li>
  <ul>
    {{#each children}}
      {{partial "tree"}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

[Here is a working demo.](http://jsbin.com/mozix/3/edit)

Comment: The partials data-template-name should start with an "_" ,so the partial name should be "_tree". Please refer http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-partial-code-helper

Comment: @Jeevi Thanks. I didnt notice that as it was working. I wondered why it worked in the first place. I guess this used to be supported. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/helpers/partial.js#L98