# Ember treeview / unlimited depth

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to load a treeview with Ember. I can display the first level, then I guess I could add an {{outlet}} tag to load the 2nd level, but I can't seem to find how to do level 3 and 4 and whatever. And actually even level 2 seems tricky cause that would be the same route with a different parameter (the current parent).

Won't bother you with what I tried, just wanted to know if anyone could give me some tips on how that could be structured?

Thanks!

Comment: to can get unlimited depth you need to use recursion

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385933/updating-ember-nested-model-and-template

Comment: @blessenm : this is from 2014 which is like 10 years ago in the emberjs development world. Considering it's not even working with the version they used (try hitting the second button), well... If this is the best I can get, I'll try to make it work though I already see many deprecated tags / functions.

Comment: @Bek seems you got some ember skills, would be cool to have a more elaborate answer, cause obviously yes that's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @de4dc0w haven't implemented such thing, but it is certainly possible ember templates support recursive structure component template can have itself inside its template. I have made ember twiddle to demonstrate that https://ember-twiddle.com/#/8752439c256b833ebfde

Comment: @de4dc0w I know its an old demo but it should still work. I got it working fine in Ember 2.2. Only modified the each helper in the templates. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/saloho/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Bek : thanks! Sorry I know I look lazy but I'm more frustrated by the hours trying to make "old" examples work when the API has changed 49 times since. Huge THANKS again!

Comment: @blessenm : message was directed to you as well but couldn't add you both in the message. So huge THANKS too :)

Comment: On a side note, I thought that the {{partial}} helper was deprecated (no trace of it in the 2.2.0 docs). So trying to solve problems without proper doc doesn't help.

Comment: @de4dc0w 'partial' is not deprecated. Here are the docs for the template helpers. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html

Comment: @blessenm hehe yeah but the API pages are not what I'd call a doc **at least for someone just starting with a framework**. The "guide" should be enough and has been enough for me for numerous frameworks. BTW from the guide _"This documentation will take you from total beginner to Ember expert."_, I read the guide but I'm far from being an expert and IMO such things as "partial" are needed for any basic app. It was in the previous guides BTW. OK not going to rant on this thread, that is another problem, and BTW thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to model the tree as data and then recursively render that data. Something like:

```
// app.hbs
{{x-tree data=treeStructure}}

// x-tree.hbs
{{#each data.children as |child|}}
  {{component child.type data=child}}
{{/each}}
```

Where `type` would be either what you want to render, or another tree.